# load font-awesome icon in ::before and ::after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I can't load icons from font awesome in pseudo-element. I tried to follow the docs but it didn't work.

```css
.x::before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

.x::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
}
```

```html
<p class="x">hello, my name is john</p>
```

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh can you help me how i shoud create demo and share?

Comment: So did you link to the resources needed by font awesome?

Comment: Adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"></link>` your code works.... so what are you doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the font-awesome stylesheet to your code and it will load the icon.

```css
.x::before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

.x::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"></link>
<p class="x">hello, my name is john</p>
```

Comment: In fact the problem was i used cdn version 6. i must used cdn version 5

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't installed fontawesome kit in your html.
please go [here](https://fontawesome.com/start) and enter your email address. They will send a verification email and then you will be provided to a link where you will find the `<script>` tag provided by them. copy and paste that in your  html file.

Answer (score 0):

ok this problem is really easy to solve:

> First thing you have to create a span tag between the
>
> tags:

Correction: no need for span tag.

```
<p class="icon-classname">hello, my name is john</p>
```

Also another thing you have to remember is to use the link for the font-awesome in your HTML file with this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css"></link>
```

and in the css file:

```
icon-classname::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
}
```

You do not need span tag to use the font-Awesome, probably the only thing that was missing in your code is the link from font-awesome.

Comment: Why would there need to be a span? There is no need with pseudo element.

Comment: that's what the font-awesome documentation says:
https://www.angularjswiki.com/fontawesome/

Comment: And what the OP is trying to do with documentation https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: yeah basically I just said the same thing your link describes.

Comment: THERE IS NO SPAN, if the OP were to add a span, there is no reason to use pseudo element, they could just add the normal font awesome classes.

Comment: Please look closer there's the code from the site: https://prnt.sc/1ur6tca , this is from the site you sent me, I have used this one before, and I tried using other tags and all that nothing else works except span tag,

Comment: YES, they are adding the pseudo to the span. In the OPs example, they would be adding it to the `<p>`

Comment: don't you see that he did the same thing I did without the span and it didn't work? It took me 30 min the first time to figure out that no other tag goes with font-awesome, the pseudo can only be added to the span element if you want font-awesome to work.

Comment: See my answer.... Where is the span?

Comment: my bad it works without the span, I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably explore [this article](https://css-tricks.com/to-double-colon-or-not-do-double-colon/)

Sometimes the problem is simple `::before` vs `:before`

I recommend that you try using `:before`. Everything else points out that your code should be working fine.